# Why react native map function is not working properly?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase firestore. Data from the firestore is logging on the console but not displaying when I use  component.

```
renderList = () => {
        const { accounts } = this.props
        accounts && accounts.map((account) => {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{account.accountName}</Text>
                    {console.log(account.accountName)}
                </View>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.renderList()}
            </>
        )
    }
```

In the above coding console.log(account.accountName) is working but it is not printing in the render method. I need to create a list with that data.

Comment: Have you tried using a renderList inside a View?

Comment: Tried, Not working

Comment: Sorry you havent returned anything inisde renderList. You created a JSX from map function but you also have to return it. 

Just put return keyword behind accounts && ...

Comment: Yes man. you're correct

Comment: If you want to learn about ES6 syntax and how JS arrays functions: https://reactdevstation.github.io/2020/03/18/es6-for-react.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please :

```
    renderList = () => {
            const { accounts } = this.props;
     if(accounts){
            return accounts.map((account) => {
                return (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{account.accountName}</Text>
                        {console.log(account.accountName)}
                    </View>
                )
            })
}
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    {this.renderList()}
                </>
            )
        }
```

hope it helps

Comment: It's working. You're a genius. What is the difference between these two?

Comment: see the thing was, you were not returning anything form the renderListView, so ive just added a return statemnt. Glad it helped. Do mark as accepted too if you think its the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too and this worked for me.
Just after the arrow ( => ) use a bracket instead of curly brace like this (  => (... your code ...)
not this    => {....}

#### Here is your EDITED code

```
renderList = () => {
        const { accounts } = this.props
        accounts && accounts.map((account) => ( // don't use curly brace! use bracket "("
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{account.accountName}</Text>
                    {console.log(account.accountName)}
                </View>
            )
        )) // and here also; not curly brace; but a bracket ")"
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.renderList()}
            </>
        )
    }
```

[image: here is my image]